# Chrome extension with device group

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-messaging

I use a device group without a server as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client-device-group). I want to know if it's possible to design a chrome extension in order to use GCM notifications in these conditions. I know I can add/remove a device using HTTP request and an API key (so emulating the server) but this approach has several problems from security point of view because I need to put my API key in the extension. What I'd like to do, instead, is to use the approach used on Android but I didn't find a way.

Comment: You can implement GCM Client on Chrome, Chrome apps and extensions can access the GCM service directly through chrome.gcm API. For more info follow this link: (https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client)

Comment: No, usually it's possible because you send the registration id to the server or as I said you can send http request directly but you have to put the api key in the extension and it's what I want.